# How to properly obtain paypal transactions from REST API

Tags: paypal

I setup a paypal rest api application for my account. I'm using the production credentials given in the hidden "Live credentials" section of the app.

I'm using the ruby gem client (https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-ruby) for this, and when I do `Payment.all( :count => 100 )` I get zero results, even though my live paypal account has payments made to it in the last couple of days.

Am I doing something wrong, or do I just not understand what the REST API should be returning?

All I'm trying to do is read my incoming payments to my paypal account.

Answer (score 2):

That call will only return the list of RESTful transactions so if you haven't received any transactions generated from the RESTful APIs, then you won't have any results.

Comment: So is there any way to do this with the rest api, or am i stuck using IPN?

Comment: You could either use IPN or you can utilize the TransactionSearch API.  You can find more information on TransactionSearch [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/)